# disabling view of folder files from website

Tags: security, .htaccess, url, directory-structure

If a person goes to my site and type a URL like www.mysite.com/admin/includes, the webpage displays the entire directory! How can I stop this? Most of the files are in PHP though, so even if anyone downloads those files, they're mostly blank, but someone just hacked my website and I'm wondering if knowing the directory structure helped them.

I need to do disable the viewing of all directory structures, while allowing the display of images like `www.mysite.com/images/image1.jpg`

Comment: The `accessibility` tag is used for helping people with disabilities (tag removed)

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file, insert the following line:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will prevent the viewing of directory indexes, whilst allowing actual files to pass through.

Note that you must have `AllowOverride Options` set in your config (this is already done in most hosting environments).